# Servant client with type variable with FromJSON contraint

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm trying to create client bindings to Web API using [servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.7.1/docs/Servant-API.html) library.
I want to be able to send any JSON objects.

```
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Except (ExceptT, runExceptT)
import           Data.Proxy
import           Network.HTTP.Client (Manager)
import           Servant.API
import           Servant.Client
import           Data.Aeson

-- | This methods accepts any instance of 'ToJSON'
--   I would like to have only this method exported from the module
send :: ToJSON a => a -> Manager -> IO (Either ServantError Result)
send x manager = runExceptT $ send_ x manager baseUrl

type MyAPI a = "acceptAnyJson" 
    :> ReqBody '[JSON] a
    :> Post '[JSON] Result

api :: ToJSON a => Proxy (MyAPI a) 
api = Proxy 

send_ :: ToJSON a => a -> Manager -> BaseUrl -> ExceptT ServantError IO Result
send_ = client api
```

Right now when I try to compile it I have error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a0’ with ‘a’
      because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      the inferred type for ‘send_’:
      ...
```

How can I parameterize my `MyAPI`, `client` and `Proxy` to accept type variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to tie the type of `api` to the type of the thing you're sending:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
send_ :: forall a. (FromJSON a) => a -> Manager -> BaseUrl -> ExceptT ServantError IO Result
send_ = client (api :: Proxy (MyAPI a))
```

or why even bother with `api` at that point:

```
send_ = client (Proxy :: Proxy (MyAPI a))
```